# sails js many to many associations not working

Tags: sails.js

### User.js

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'user',

  attributes: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    pets: {                     //integer
     collection:'pet',
     via:'owners'
    }
  }
};
```

================================

```
Pet.js
------
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'pet',

  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    breed: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    type: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    owners: {                    //integer 
      collection:'user',
      via:'pets'
    }
  }
};
```

But when i hit the blueprint api http://localhost:1337/user or http://localhost:1337/pet i dont get associated records

Here is the output in ARC or postman for  user and pet

```
[
  {
"pets": [],
"firstName": "a",
"lastName": "aa",
"id": 1
},
  {
"pets": [],
"firstName": "b",
"lastName": "bb",
"id": 2
},
  {
"pets": [],
"firstName": "c",
"lastName": "cc",
"id": 3
},
  {
"pets": [],
"firstName": "d",
"lastName": "dd",
"id": 4
},
  {
"pets": [],
"firstName": "e",
"lastName": "ee",
"id": 5
}
],


[
  {
"owners": [],
"id": 1,
"breed": "dalmatian",
"type": "male",
"name": "tom"
},
  {
"owners": [],
"id": 2,
"breed": "labrador",
"type": "female",
"name": "kg"
},
  {
"owners": [],
"id": 3,
"breed": "doberman",
"type": "male",
"name": "tq"
},
  {
"owners": [],
"id": 4,
"breed": "puppy",
"type": "male",
"name": "yu"
}
]
```

One to many association works fine but don't know  what am i missing in many to many ?
i tried removing the id column from both the models but that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a pet to an owner with the [`add` Blueprint API](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/add-to):

```
POST /:model/:id/:association/:fk
```

example :

```
http://localhost:1337/user/1/pets/2
```

This will add the pet with id 2 to the owner with id 1.

Comment: I tried using add method 
User.findOne(1).exec(function(err, user) {
      if (err) // handle error

        // Queue up a record to be inserted into the join table
        user.pets.add(2);

      // Save the user, creating the new associations in the join table
      user.save(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
      });
but still getting the same response 
Also tried to hit directly using postman
http://localhost:1337/user/1/pets/2 using post method but getting an error
"message": "[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] ",

Comment: What is shown in the console with this code ?`User.findOne(1).populateAll().then(function(user){ sails.log.debug(user); }).catch(function(err){ sails.log.error(err); });`

Comment: i added the above code this is the response

debug: { pets: [], firstName: 'a', lastName: 'aa', id: 1 }

should  i be using populateall() ? 
because it should directly work with blueprint /user right ?

Comment: i am hitting blueprint apis still getting empty object in owners for pet and pets in user